# Alfresco session timeout

Tags: session, alfresco, session-timeout

We are using alfresco 5.2.3 enterprise with ADF 3.4.0
The web.xml files in our both alfresco and share war has 60
And for ADF we have not found any session timeout settings or config.
So, ideally the session should not expire before 60 mins, but the customer is complaining that after remaining idle for around 15 mins, their session expires/logs out. They need to relogin.

So, what should be the ideal way to make the session valid for actual 60 mins and not just 15 mins.

I tried overriding the session timeout using the following link but it's not working:
[Overriding alfresco timeout](https://github.com/malcolmcif/alfresco-extend-session-timeouts/blob/master/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/custom-authentication-timeout-context.xml)

Also tried setting the following property in alfresco-global.properties file with different values:
authentication.ticket.validDuration=PT1H

But does not work.
The same behaviour is noted when we use ADF url as well as Share url.
Share Url actually logs out the user, ADF url mostly invalidates the session so our custom actions do not appear against the documents if user remains idle for 15 mins.

NOTE: There is no SSO integration done for our project.

Any suggestions or pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out with multiple options:

```
authentication.ticket.ticketsExpire=true
to
authentication.ticket.ticketsExpire=false

authentication.ticket.expiryMode=AFTER_INACTIVITY
to
authentication.ticket.expiryMode=DO_NOT_EXPIRE

authentication.ticket.useSingleTicketPerUser=false
to
authentication.ticket.useSingleTicketPerUser=true
```

But, none of the above settings after restart give any impact on the behaviour. So, this session timeout settings are mostly carried forward from the proxy server or load balancer settings and applied here.

Comment: One observation: When I set  authentication.ticket.useSingleTicketPerUser=false i.e multiple tickets for each user ; in this case the active session count in alfresco admin console (https://alfresco-repo-server.domain.com/alfresco/s/enterprise/admin/admin-activesessions) keep on growing. So some one doing this should keep that in mind too while configuring. Else, you can keep the default setting - authentication.ticket.useSingleTicketPerUser=true